# A pointer to the array in p1=Table in Table =p0 Eror

Tags: list-manipulation

There is a circle of 10 points. How to draw another circle around this point from the first array? And so it drags along in the first circle. As in the program, drag the red. The coordinates of the points in the first p0.  the second Table p1 wants to read a pointer to the Table p0.

```
Deploy[
Graphics[
{
PolozeniRasceta = 10;(*----Сколько положений B вокруг A считать*)
ShagUgla = (2*Pi)/PolozeniRasceta;
xA = 0;
yA = 0;
xB = 0.25;
yB = 0.25;
xC = 0.6;
yC = 0.5;
xD = 0.8;
yD = 0;
AB = Dynamic[
EuclideanDistance[{xA, yA}, {xB, yB}]];(*----длинна AB*)
StartUgol = 
Dynamic[Mod[ArcTan[xB - xA, yB - yA], 
  2 Pi]];(*----стартовый угол AB*)

 NaidenUgol = StartUgol;
a0 = Dynamic[
 If[(xB - xC)*(yD - yB) - (xD - xB)*(yB - yC) > 0, 
  1, -1]];(*----точка C выше AD?*)
(*----*)
BC = Dynamic[EuclideanDistance[{xB, yB}, {xC, yC}]];
BD = Dynamic[EuclideanDistance[{xB, yB}, {xD, yD}]];
CD = Dynamic[EuclideanDistance[{xC, yC}, {xD, yD}]];
(*Alfa0=ArcCos[(BC^2+BD^2-CD^2)/(2*BC*BD)];*)
(*Alfa0=Dynamic[ArcCos[(BC^2+BD^2-CD^2)/(2*BC*BD)]];*)
(*----*)
RGBColor[10, 0, 0],
PointSize[0.03],
Point[Dynamic[{xA, yA}]],
Point[Dynamic[{xB, yB}]],
Point[Dynamic[{xC, yC}]],
Point[Dynamic[{xD, yD}]],

Line[{Dynamic[{xA, yA}], Dynamic[{xB, yB}]}],

Locator[Dynamic[{xA, yA}], None],
Locator[Dynamic[{xB, yB}], None],
Locator[Dynamic[{xC, yC}], None],
Locator[Dynamic[{xD, yD}], None],
(*----------------------*)   
Text[StyleForm[Dynamic[
  Alfa0
  ], FontSize -> 20, FontWeight -> "Bold"], {-0.8, -0.8}],
(*----------------------*)  

(*-----массив координат B----------------*)   
p0 = Dynamic[Table[
  {
   If[NaidenUgol > 2*Pi, NaidenUgol = NaidenUgol - (2*Pi)];
   NaidenUgol = NaidenUgol + ShagUgla;
   xA + Cos[NaidenUgol]*AB,
   yA + Sin[NaidenUgol]*AB
   }, {i, 0, PolozeniRasceta}]];
RGBColor[0, 0, 0],
PointSize[0.02],
Point[p0],
(*-----массив координат B----------------*)   

(*-----массив координат С----------------*)   
 (*(*-----ошибка----------------*)   
NaidenUgol=1;
p1=Dynamic[Table[   
{
If[NaidenUgol>2*Pi,NaidenUgol=NaidenUgol-(2*Pi)];
NaidenUgol=NaidenUgol+ShagUgla;
p0[[1,1]]+Cos[NaidenUgol]*0.2,
p0[[1,2]]+Sin[NaidenUgol]*0.2
},{i,0,PolozeniRasceta}]];
RGBColor[0,0,0],
PointSize[0.02],
Point[p1]
(*-----массив координат С----------------*)   *)



(*----------------------------------------------------------------------\
---------------------*)   
},
AspectRatio -> 1,
Axes -> True,
PlotRange -> 1
]]

(*================================================================*)
(*================================================================*)
(*----------NEW WORKING CODE-------Now works correctly----*)
(*
 Bug1. If Table1 undertook a variable, it is impossible 
  to take  in Table2. Fails in the formula does not say the error.Bug2.
  Pointer to an array type a1 [[i, 1]] = a0 [[2,1]] + Cos [Angle2] *  
  0.2; 
  Do not work inside the Table, Table in general is better to draw the
  point. 
  *)

  {xA,yA}={0,0};
  {xB,yB}={0.25,0.25};
  Positions=10;
  AngleStep=(2 Pi)/Positions;
  AB=Dynamic[EuclideanDistance[{xA,yA},{xB,yB}]];(*----length AB  must
  updated*)
  StartAngle=Dynamic[Mod[ArcTan[xB-xA,yB-yA],2 Pi]];(*---Start 
   Angle AB    must updated*)
  Angle=StartAngle;
  (*---------------------------------------------*)
   a0=Array[0&,{Positions,2}];
  a1=Array[0&,{Positions,2}];
  (*---------Array B-------------------------*)
    For[i=1,i<Positions+1,i++,
  If[Angle>2*Pi,Angle=Angle-(2*Pi)];(* if more 2 Pi*)
  Angle=Angle+AngleStep; (* add AngleStep*)
  a0[[i,1]]=Dynamic@xA+Cos[Angle]*AB;
  a0[[i,2]]=Dynamic@yA+Sin[Angle]*AB
  ];
  (*-------------------------*)
   p0=Table[{
   a0[[t,1]],
   a0[[t,2]]},
   {t,1,Positions}];
   (*---------Array B-------------------------*)
   (*---------Array C-------------------------*)
   Angle2=0.1; 
   For[i=1,i<Positions+1,i++,
   If[Angle2>2*Pi,Angle2=Angle2-(2*Pi)];(* if more 2 Pi*)
   Angle2=Angle2+AngleStep; (* add AngleStep*)
   a1[[i,1]]=a0[[2,1]]+Cos[Angle2]*0.2;
   a1[[i,2]]=a0[[2,2]]+Sin[Angle2]*0.2
   ];
   p1=Table[{
   a1[[t,1]],
   a1[[t,2]]
   },{t,1,Positions}];
    (*---------Array C-------------------------*)
    Graphics[
    {
     RGBColor[10,0,0],
     PointSize[0.03],
     Point[Dynamic[{xA,yA}]],
      Point[Dynamic[{xB,yB}]],
      Line[{Dynamic[{xA,yA}],Dynamic[{xB,yB}]}],
     RGBColor[0,0,0],
    PointSize[0.02],
    Point[p0],
     Point[p1],
   Locator[Dynamic[{xA,yA}],None],
   Locator[Dynamic[{xB,yB}],None]
   },
   AspectRatio1,AxesTrue,PlotRange1]
   (*The video card is generally not used, probably programmers 
   wolfram  newbies.*)
```

Comment: From the text of the question I don't expect anyone to be able to fathom what your actual question is. Also please try to boil down your code to a minimal working example

Comment: Why eror here?
p1=Dynamic[Table[   
{
If[NaidenUgol>2*Pi,NaidenUgol=NaidenUgol-(2*Pi)];
NaidenUgol=NaidenUgol+ShagUgla;
p0[[1,1]]+Cos[NaidenUgol]*0.2,
p0[[1,2]]+Sin[NaidenUgol]*0.2
},{i,0,PolozeniRasceta}]];
RGBColor[0,0,0],
PointSize[0.02],
Point[p1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is similar to the one described in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66591/how-can-i-use-parts-of-lists-with-dynamic). The neat solution would be to remove `Dynamic` everywhere and wrap the whole code in `Manipulate` (see my version below). It works well and hopefully as you intended.

```
Manipulate[

 Positions = 10;
 AngleStep = (2 Pi)/Positions;

 AB = EuclideanDistance[{pA[[1]], pA[[2]]}, {pB[[1]], pB[[2]]}];
 Angle = Mod[ArcTan[pB[[1]] - pA[[1]], pB[[2]] - pA[[2]]], 2 Pi];

 cA = Table[
   {
    pA[[1]] + Cos[Angle + i*AngleStep]*AB,
    pA[[2]] + Sin[Angle + i*AngleStep]*AB
    },
   {i, 0, Positions}
   ];

 cB = Table[
   {
    pB[[1]] + Cos[i*AngleStep]*0.2,
    pB[[2]] + Sin[i*AngleStep]*0.2
    },
   {i, 0, Positions}
   ];

 cC = Table[
   {
    cA[[3, 1]] + Cos[i*AngleStep]*0.2,
    cA[[3, 2]] + Sin[i*AngleStep]*0.2
    },
   {i, 0, Positions}
   ];

 Graphics[
  {
   RGBColor[1, 0, 0], PointSize[0.03], Point[{pA, pB}],
   RGBColor[0, 0, 0], PointSize[0.02], Point[cA], Point[cB], Point[cC]
   },
  AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 1],

 {{pA, {0, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None},
 {{pB, {0.25, 0.25}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}
 ]
```

Comment: Error, just run the code works. Error in the commented out section. p0 [[1, 1]] is that correct? Why again a mistake?

Plus is not a Graphics primitive or directive.

Coordinate {{-0.2990861733586729, -0.40556538093832095`}, {-0.16829419696157932`, -0.16829419696157932`, 9.831705803038421}} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.

Comment: (*-----Eror----*)
    (*p0[{1,1}]+(Cos[Angle]*0.2),     (*<--------------------------Eror*)
    p0[{1,2}]+(Sin[Angle]*0.2)*)
    (*-----Eror----*)

https://dropmefiles.com/YAjZp

Comment: Very strange you have a forum on all other any code is very simple 1 button is released: [HASKELL] [/ HASKELL] any people intuitively understand how to select the code. And then the gaps are very strange and uncomfortable. Fix and test the code, read the first post, I do not know how to add the code in comments

Comment: We need arrays of vertex coordinates B for the animation in my code the second a circle drawn around 3 points instead xB. And when drawing oddly late point B segment If (Angle + i * AngleStep)> 2 pi is not an error? Strange.

Comment: @Excalibur921 Did you try the final version of my code? It should solve your problem. Unfortunately, I don't understand your last comment, please be more clear. You can also try to explain it in Russian if it is easier =)

Comment: Так вы знаете русский? Уверен гугл транслейт опять накрутит что то...порой волосы дыбом от его перевода.

Очень странный у вас форум, можно менять сообщения…в других ставят новые сообщения и человек заходит  и видит что добавлено N сообщений. И почему нет уведомлений об ответе автоматически на почту регистрации? 

Попробуйте нарисовать  малую окружность вокруг  например 3 точки большой окружности. В прошлом коде Table выдавал ошибку.
Массивы координат   cB cA доступны для расчета далее в коде?

Comment: I apologize to the community for switching to Russian but otherwise it will be very difficult to understand the problem (Google Translate from Russian is not very good). @Excalibur921 Да, знаю. Я тоже здесь недавно, по-тихоньку привыкаю. Массивы координат `cA` и `cB` в пределах `Manipulate` доступны. Я переписал код с использованием координат `cA` и дорисовал окружность для еще одной точки. Решило ли это вашу задачу?

Comment: Код вешает математику. Математика 8. Уверен баг в Table. чем вам не нравиться мой работающий код внизу?

Comment: Зачем вообще эта лаговая Table? Вы читали два бага в ней написал в коде на английском  =)? Почему не сделать через For и array, это всем понятно и опятьTable это  For и array скрытый от пользователя. Не хочет рисовать Point через  For.Только так извращенно. Странно, 5 чел не поняли как рисовать круг вокруг круга? Или не увидели единственный закомментированный  участок кода? Размещал на нескольких форумах никто не справился кроме меня с вашими доработками когда перестали таскаться точки.

Comment: А вообще  похоже тут алгоритмическая ошибка программистов когда Point это векторный объект который таскает процессор и каждый раз делает ненужные расчеты растеризации и масштаба+ куча расчетов изменения масштаба картинки. Если бы программисты волфрама запустили примитивы под OpenGL скорость бы интерактивных расчетов резко возросла. Когда таскаю 1 точку процессор загружен на 100%. Видеокарта вообще не используется. И зачем тут странное ограничение на количество символов? Мда…

Comment: @Excalibur921 Пардон, поправил ошибку. При определении `Locator` в конце `Manipulate` надо инициализировать координаты `pB` в числах, а не ссылаться на еще не посчитаный массив `cA`. Все должно работать теперь. Мне вариант с `Manipulate` больше нравится, потому что он занимает меньше кода и более интуитивный. Но о вкусах не спорят. Если я на ваш вопрос ответил, отметьте пожалуйста его как принятый ответ. Мне за это начислят баллы в репутацию. Спасибо!

Comment: А что вам дают эти баллы? Я не знаю где...обычно на форумах есть “ кнопка это ответ”…

Comment: Ну, например коммнетировать другие вопросы. Сейчас мне эта функция не доступна. Нажмите на галочку слева от моего ответа. Подробности [здесь](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).