# InputField enabled or disabled with two dynamic variables

Tags: dynamic, inputfield

Dynamic has been really useful for me but it is as well not easy to understand also. I am doing a calculation where I want some of the input fields enabled or disabled depending on where I am in the computation.

```
Row[{Style[" Report the result ", 13, Blue, Editable -> False], 
Checkbox[Dynamic[dod], {False, True}, Enabled -> Dynamic@Switch[sd,
   1, False,
   0, False,
   4, True,
   3, True,
   2, True]] Style[" with ", 13, Blue, Editable -> False], 
   InputField[Dynamic[NoPd], Number, FieldSize -> {12, 1.5}, 
   Enabled -> Dynamic[dod]]}]
```

Here sd is switching during the computation to false which makes the checkbox disabled. But the corresponding input field only depends on "dod".
That means the field is enabled during the computation if the checkbox was checked before the calculation started. I would like to be able to disable the input field during the computation. I am trying to find a way to do something like

```
InputField[Dynamic[NoPd], Number, FieldSize -> {12, 
1.5},Enabled->If[MatchQ[{Dynamic[dod], Dynamic@Switch[sd,
   1, False,
   0, False,
   4, True,
   3, True,
   2, True]}, False], False]]
```

For the InputField. I know that {Dynamic[dod], Dynamic[sd]} is not a list. I can't really take Dynamic[dod] as a variable. 
My question somewhat similar to 
[How can I use parts of lists with Dynamic?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66591/how-can-i-use-parts-of-lists-with-dynamic)

but I couldn't adapt the solution of that question to mine. Please let me know if my question is not clear enough.

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Does this give what you need: `Row[{Style[" Report the result ", 13, Blue, Editable -> False], 
  Checkbox[Dynamic[dod], {False, True}, 
    Enabled -> 
     Dynamic[cbenabled = 
       Switch[sd, 1, False, 0, False, 4, True, 3, True, 2, 
        True]]] Style[" with ", 13, Blue, Editable -> False], 
  InputField[Dynamic[NoPd], Number, FieldSize -> {12, 1.5}, 
   Enabled -> Dynamic[dod && cbenabled]]}]`?

Comment: @kglr Exactly, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Row[{Style[" Report the result ", 13, Blue, Editable -> False], 
   Checkbox[Dynamic[dod], {False, True}, 
      Enabled -> Dynamic[cbenabled = Switch[sd, 1, False, 0, False,
         4, True, 3, True, 2, True]]] Style[" with ", 13, Blue, 
            Editable -> False], InputField[Dynamic[NoPd], Number, FieldSize -> {12, 1.5}, 
              Enabled -> Dynamic[dod && cbenabled]]}]
```